# RabbitMQ in Nestjs, error with Producer and Consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I'm trying to implement microservices in Nestjs with Rabbitmq but i get in Producer :
Disconnected from RMQ. Trying to reconnect.
[Nest] 21700  - 08/05/2023, 9:01:28 PM   ERROR [ClientProxy] Object:

`{ "err": { "code": 406, "classId": 60, "methodId": 20 } }`

and Consumer still OK ,
Here my producer :

```
@Get()
async getUser() {
  return this.authService.send(
    {
    cmd : 'get-user'
    },
    {}
    )
}
```

and here my consumer :

```
@MessagePattern({cmd : 'get-user'})
async getUser(@Ctx() context : RmqContext){
  const channel = context.getChannelRef()
  const message = context.getMessage()
  channel.ack(message)

  return {user: "User"}
}
```

and here is configuration in counsumer and it's the same in Producer:`

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AuthModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService)
  const USER = configService.get('RABBITMQ_USER');
  const PASSWORD = configService.get('RABBITMQ_PASS')
  const HOST = configService.get('RABBITMQ_HOST');
  const QUEUE = configService.get('RABBITMQ_AUTH_QUEUE');

   app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
      transport : Transport.RMQ,
      options : {
        urls : [`amqp://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@${HOST}`],
        noAck : false,
        queue : QUEUE,
        queueOptions : {
          durable : true
        }
      }
      
   })

   app.startAllMicroservices();
}
```

What could be wrong? the server is working...

Answer (score 0):

this message usually comes from the already declared queue that has some changes after being deployed.

Easiest solution to this is to login to your Rabbit management console, manually delete the Queue in question and restart the NestJS app so it can re-create the queue with new settings.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I fix this error by edit noAck from true to false

Comment: Ok, but in your code example noAck is already set to false.. just keep in mind that if you set it to true - you will be loosing the ability to manually acknowledge the message

Comment: oh sorry my bad actually I fixed by edit noAck from false to true. I followed to this https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/11966. If you set noAck : true on producer and noAck: false on consumer, it will active like v9